# Force GPG in GPGME to use a cipher other than CAST5

Tags: c++, encryption, gnupg, gpgme

I would like to use GPGME to encrypt data (no files) and save the data in a database. I learned that GPGME with OpenPGP as protocol will encrypt the data with GPG and CAST5. CAST5, that is what my command line is telling me if I check gpg2 with:

```
LANG=C gpg2 --verbose --symmetric
gpg: using cipher CAST5
```

I dont know why it doesn't use the [new AES-128 default value](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/86305/what-is-the-default-cipher-algorithm-for-gnupg). But i guess I doesn't have the latest release available (nor does the package manager in my debian system).

I would really like to configure GPG to use AES for encryption by setting the  corresponding values in the gpg.conf file mentioned [here](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2013-February/046109.html) and on the [homepage of GPG](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/GPG-Configuration.html). So I tried to fetch the information about the file location by using `gpgme_get_engine_info` and looking at `home_dir`but this path seems empty. The `file_name` is `usr/bin/gpg2`. But well, there is no gpg.conf.  Strictly speaking there is no gpg.conf in my system at all.
So what should I do if this file is missing? Or is there a way to set the value programmatically with GPGME? I only found

```
gpgme_ctx_set_engine_info (gpgme_ctx_t ctx, gpgme_protocol_t proto, const char *file_name, const char *home_dir)
```

So I could create a new config and set the path with this function. But this would presume that I know how this file looks like. Sadly I don't.

Answer (score 1):

I found a [good example](https://github.com/ioerror/duraconf/blob/master/configs/gnupg/gpg.conf) of a pgp.conf file which shows how to set the prefered values of the ciphers and hashfunctions. This is a excerpt:

```
# list of personal digest preferences. When multiple digests are supported by
# all recipients, choose the strongest one
personal-cipher-preferences AES256 AES192 AES CAST5

# list of personal digest preferences. When multiple ciphers are supported by
# all recipients, choose the strongest one
personal-digest-preferences SHA512 SHA384 SHA256 SHA224

# message digest algorithm used when signing a key
cert-digest-algo SHA512

# This preference list is used for new keys and becomes the default for
# "setpref" in the edit menu
default-preference-list SHA512 SHA384 SHA256 SHA224 AES256 AES192 AES CAST5 ZLIB BZIP2 ZIP Uncompressed
```